# NestJS and Mongoose Not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, api, mongoose, nosql, nestjs

## Hello!

So, so when i request some data from the database (JSON), it works, but when a try to push data in it and send it back to the database, then it gives me this:

```
[ { os: 'win32', sessionID: '18ef6ccf-4889-4fc6-a457-c235c5d5f16b' } ]
{ os: 'win32', sessionID: 'eb9feaf6-29c5-4481-b935-ade2ca3e82aa' }
2
```

Why?

Can you help me? Thanks!

Heres the code:

```
          let user = await this.usersModel.findOne({
            username: data.username,
          });

          console.log(user)

          let userSessions = await JSON.parse(user.sessions);

          console.log(userSessions);

          let newSessions = userSessions.push({
            os: process.platform,
            sessionID: sessionID,
          });

          console.log({
            os: process.platform,
            sessionID: sessionID,
          });

          console.log(newSessions);

          await this.usersModel.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
              _id: user._id,
            },
            {
              $set: {
                sessions: JSON.stringify(newSessions),
              },
            }
          );
```

Users collection (Exported from MongoDB Compass):

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63a319a93e17b629d7bdd8f3"
  },
  "username": "Alms",
  "password": "$2b$10$jVwFs6kc93ShowPhYXwCI.bTTJHvMZUyOOjw1hXOJGV/e0wQsDQa2",
  "pfp": "default.png",
  "created_at": "Wed Dec 21 2022 15:35:21 GMT+0100 (közép-európai téli idő)",
  "__v": 0,
  "notif": "[]",
  "sessions": "2"
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63a355cd5568c9b72526a9fb"
  },
  "username": "Alms2",
  "password": "$2b$10$pYXqp0DS952HLlD3E3LXs.Y89hoYOVV82HF1ibp7Y/9ptMpEYrXce",
  "pfp": "default.png",
  "created_at": "Wed Dec 21 2022 19:51:57 GMT+0100 (közép-európai téli idő)",
  "__v": 0,
  "notif": "[]",
  "sessions": ""
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63a40c846b4dd1a7b08c51bb"
  },
  "username": "Alms3",
  "password": "$2b$10$K8TU6FijRcVOTM4x6JVo5un21dxZht6JIUHMIvWMSV0SMmKqyT1Ra",
  "pfp": "default.png",
  "created_at": "Thu Dec 22 2022 08:51:32 GMT+0100 (közép-európai téli idő)",
  "__v": 0,
  "notif": "",
  "sessions": ""
}]
```

Everything a tried is in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) returns the new length of the array, not the array itself.

You initialize the userSessions variable to an array

```
let userSessions = await JSON.parse(user.sessions)
```

So after you invoke the Array.push method:

```
let newSessions = userSessions.push({
            os: process.platform,
            sessionID: sessionID,
          })
```

`userSessions` will contain an array that is now 1 element longer, and `newSessions` will contain the length of the `userSessions` array.

So when you get to the update operation, the value you should be sending to the database is `userSessions`:

```
              $set: {
                sessions: JSON.stringify(userSessions),
              }
```